# How can I determine if a button clicked by user or by code?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to fire `click event` like this :

```
bool m=false;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("button1 clicke!");
        button1.Tag = "system";
        ButtonAutomationPeer peer = new ButtonAutomationPeer(button1);
        IInvokeProvider invokeProv = peer.GetPattern(PatternInterface.Invoke) as IInvokeProvider;
        if (m==false)
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                invokeProv.Invoke();
                m = true;
            }
    }
```

I want to show this `MessageBox` only 3 time. it's worked but when I click this button again, `MessageBox` showed only once.

Comment: XAML, WPF and UWP are designed with the MVVM pattern in mind. While you can use other approaches, doing so looses about 90% of XAMLs power and runs into issues every other point. That does not look like the MVVM pattern at all. A few years back I wrote a intro into MVVM that should get you started: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b1a8bf14-4acd-4d77-9df8-bdb95b02dbe2/lets-talk-about-mvvm?forum=wpf Debugging help for people not using MVVM is limited at best.

Comment: when you do an event click on your code you can create a  dummy button
  `Button b = new Button() { Name = "dummy" }; `
and then inside the `Click` event check for button name

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Can you explain your solution in example?

Comment: It should not matter where it comes from (user or code). If it does you should create a different event for code generated clicks (or just use a public method on the button to call) and share common code using a private method. Or do you plan to use a lot of if/else constructs to act based on the origin? That seems like a bad idea to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
int i = 1;
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("button1 clicked!");

    ButtonAutomationPeer peer = new ButtonAutomationPeer(button1);
    IInvokeProvider invokeProv = peer.GetPattern(PatternInterface.Invoke) as IInvokeProvider;
    i++;
    if (i != 4)
    {
        invokeProv.Invoke();
    }
    else
    {
        i = 1;
    }
}
```